# ExtJS 3 and Highcharts, JsonStore problem while loading data

Tags: python, json, extjs, highcharts

i'm trying to chart some data using Highcharts in a EXTJS 3 window.
With a fixed array of data everything works but i need to chart data taken from a python cgi which returns a json.
This is how the python cgi creates my data (a slice of, i skipped the connection to the db and so on):

```
    query = "select timestamp, value from "+measure_table+" where id_resource = 280 and timestamp < '2011-07-13 03:59:00'"
    #execute the query
    cur.execute(query)
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    #create the empty json data rpeository to be filled in
    json_root = { 'fields': ['timestamp', 'value'], 'data':[] }

    for row in rows:
            json_root['data'].append({'timestamp':str(row[0]), 'value':row[1]})

    #spit out the json and we are done!
    req.write(str(json_root))
```

And this is the js in which i try to load this data:

```
        var jproxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'the url where to find the cgi'
    });
    var jstore = new Ext.data.Store({
            proxy: jproxy,
            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                    idProperty: 'timestamp',
                    root: 'data',

                    fields: [
                            {name: 'timestamp', mapping: 'timestamp'},
                            {name: 'value', mapping: 'value'},
                        ]
            })
    });
```

Then i create the window and the chart.
2 questions now: the 1st is quite simple: what's wrong with this code? firebug console says:

> o is undefined
>
> if(o.metaData){

at line 26042 of ext-all-debug.js, one of the debug scripts i've included in my html header.
The window is already created but of course there's no chart in it. Which kind of error is this? if i comment with a big /* .... */ the creation of the proxy and the store the error disappears, so the problem should be there.
EDIT: i've fixed this very problem, i loaded the store with the wrong function..i was using jstore.loadData() instead of jstore.load(), my fault..sorry

The second question is: is this (the following code) the correct way to chart data with highcharts from a jsonstore?
(we are within the chart creation, i don't post the entire code 'cause it works and probably it's not useful to post it)

```
                            xField: 'timestamp',
                            store: jstore,
                            series: [{
                                    yField: 'value'
                            }]
    }
```

Many many thanks for any answer!

EDIT: new problem after i fixed the loading of the data:

```
too much recursion
jqextend(),DanaI...xtjs.js (riga 81)
merge(),DanaI...xtjs.js (riga 92)
Chart (),DanaI....src.js (riga 3922)
options = Object { chart={...}, title={...}, altri elementi...}
callback = undefined
draw(),DanaI...hart.js (riga 229)
call(),DanaI...ebug.js (riga 1547)
, copy);
```

This is firebug console output..too much recursion? which recursion? I'm not using any recursive function in my code..

Answer (score 0):

`dict.__str__` will in most cases not produce correct json. Use the `json` module.

Example:

```
import json
...
req.write(json.dumps(json_root)
```

And remember to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` (some javascript frameworks use the header value to determine the correct action to take with the data).

Comment: The json given by the python cgi is correct, i use it in another application (a grid) and everything works correctly..(i use the same proxy & store too, so i can't figure out what's the problem..)

Comment: You should use json/simplejson in any case, since ``dict.__str__`` in very simple cases will produce invalid JSON (for instance if a value is None). Have no idea about the highcharts issue, I've only loaded data using javascript literals myself.